# PHP mkdir function returns error when called

Tags: php

I am trying to create 3 folders based on the email address of a user. I have one main folder, then the folder named after the email address, and finally a folder named images or tracks or chains.  I am passing the paths to a function which should create them. However, nothing is happening. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
public function createFolder($email){
    $this->email=$email;
    $this->pictureDirectoryPath = "../Uploads/$this->email/images";
    $this->uploadedTracksPath = "../Uploads/$this->email/tracks";
    $this->chainsPath = "../Uploads/$this->email/chains";

    //Calling the function doIt(path) to create the acutal directory.
    //The desired path is passed as a parameter

     doIt($this->pictureDirectoryPath);
     doIt($this->uploadedTracksPath);
     doIt($this->chainsPath);

}

//Function doIt() which is supposed to create a directory 
//However, nothing happens when it is called..
public function doIt($path){
    if (!mkdir($path, 0777, true)) {
            die('Failed to create folders...');
        }
}
```

Comment: *"returns error when called"* - being?

Comment: `$this->email`?  don't do that. email addresses can contain characters that are ILLEGAL for use in file/path names. e.g. `foo/bar@example.com` is a perfectly valid address, but an illegal directory name.

Comment: I didn't know that!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call functions/methods within a class you need to add `$this->` or `self::` depending on if it's static or not.

```
 $this->doIt($this->pictureDirectoryPath);
 $this->doIt($this->uploadedTracksPath);
 $this->doIt($this->chainsPath);
```